# Formatting .NET TimeSpan in unityscript

Tags: .net, datetime, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to format a .NET TimeSpan in Unity with unityscript.

I've imported `System`, and I'm trying to do this:

```
c.timeLeft = (now - c.endTime).ToString("HH:mm:ss.f");
```

`c.timeLeft` is a String.

`now` is `DateTime.Now`

`c.endTime` is a `DateTime`

`now -c.endTime` returns a TimeSpan

Unity tells me

```
No appropriate version of 'System.TimeSpan.ToString' for the argument list '(String)'        was found.
```

But the .NET Documentation tells me that `String.ToString(String)` is [valid.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx)

What's going on? How can I use the .NET methods like I'd expect?

Comment: Unity? Are you talking about the Unity3d game engine or about the Unity IoC container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wait

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx

Supported in: 4.5, 4

Unity uses .NET 2.0

That's why I can't use `TimeSpan.ToString(String)`, because it doesn't exist with my version of .NET

Comment: Use string.Format() instead